# iPhone M3U Audio Streaming without quicktime

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming

I have M3U audio url for a radio in my iPhone application. I would like to play that without use of default quick time player.

Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVPlayer in the AVFoundation framework.